# Rownum in linq to xml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-xml

i am working with xml using c# and linq to xml
but the file is too large, so there is a way to use something like rownum ?

Example:

**Select * from table a where a.rownum < 10**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to to xml is a read - to - memory beast. So, if your xml file is too large to fit in memory you may need to resort to an xmlreader solution. 
If you can load entire xml file to memory with xelement, then you can use the enumerable Select overload with indexing.

You can use something like the following extension method:

```
 namespace Variatron.Enumerables
 {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

   public static class SeriesExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitToSeries<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 seriesSize)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return TakeAsSeries(enumerator, seriesSize);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> TakeAsSeries<T>(IEnumerator<T> sourceEnumerator, Int32 seriesSize)
    {
        var count = 0;
        do
        {
            count += 1;

            yield return sourceEnumerator.Current;
        }
        while (count < seriesSize && sourceEnumerator.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but it's not in the context of what you're trying to accomplish.  If rownum is numeric, it will return all rows that are less than 10.  The 10 is the numeric, but not the size.  For example, if the column rownum contains the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,...}, it will return 1 through 9.  These are not size of the rows, but the numbers the command finds.

Comment: Ok, but how can i do that using Linq to XML ?